# Can three dimensional data be represented in csv (or tsv)?

Tags: csv

I have a task at hand in which I need to represent graphically on canvas with help of the d3.js library some salary averages for every job in graph bars by countries. The task complicates itself when the jobs are grouped by sector. 
A sector contains multiple jobs and every job has a different salary. A two dimensional data would be easy to represent but my question is, is it possible to carry this nested or hierarchical information by means of a csv file (according to the csv specification a csv is merely two dimensional).
Attached you will find a representation of the table with fake amounts , the table has lots more countries and sectors/salaries.
[image: this is a snapshot of the table with fake amounts]

Comment: The question is, what kind of chart do you want. A [bubble chart](http://green-horizons.eu/scoreboard/chart/e/405+362,361,367+2012+BE,DK,FR,DE,IE,ES,SE) for example is capable of displaying three-dimensional data: x and y coordinates plus the size of the bubble.

Answer (score 3):

Pivot your sector groupings so that they're just another column for each job, e.g.,

```csv
JOB_TITLE, SALARY-AUSTRALIA, SALARY-BELGIUM, SALARY-FRANCE, SECTOR
Copywriter, 46897, 46897, 63871, Artworker
"Creative Director", 94156, 94156, 89032, Artworker
...
```

Answer (score 3):

A CSV file could carry information at one dimension per column at the cost of a lot of redundant information, but this is how tools like Tableau etc prefer things

```
Sector  Title   Country Salary
Artworker   Copywriter  46897   Australia
Artworker   Copywriter  46897   Belgium
Artworker   Copywriter  63871   France
Artworker   Creative Director   94156   Australia
... etc
```

Your problem then is how to format into this structure from whatever format you have at the moment. OpenRefine - http://openrefine.org/ -  does this sort of thing well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am relatively new with handling data from excel (this is my source in this case) but I found this youtube video that does exactly what I want. Convert pivot table (data that is nested) into a standart table. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IwReVDJ7BAI